# Problems with writing a programm in Haskell with signature IO[(Int, Int)]

Tags: haskell, input, io

I have a real problems with programm, which should be written with signature  IO[(Int, Int)].
For me, as really beginner, it's quite hard to understand how it should look like.
So,this is task:
You should write a procedure with takes lines from user until empty line. After that it should return every line length. I try to make it more understandable with example

*Main> Take

kdfdfdf

dfdfeer

ererere

[(7,7),(7,0)]

Reading part it's quite understandable, unless, it's doesn't work actually as I want

```
Read
 = do
    putStrLn "User, your turn!" 
    line <- getLine
if line==""
    then return ...
    else do
        line <-Read
        return line {- actually doesn't return a line -}
```

I will be very glad, if someone make me understand how to write this

Answer (score 5):

What exactly do you want Read to do? As is, it won't compile for a few reasons. You can't name a function or constant starting with a capital letter, those are reserved for Data constructors. Also, I'm sure you know, but the line `return ...` isn't valid syntax in Haskell.

I don't really understand why you want a list of pairs either if you just want to return the lengths of each line then something like this would work.

```
lineLengths :: IO [Int]
lineLengths = do
    putStrLn "User, your turn!"
    line <- getLine
    if line == ""
        then return []
        else do
            moreLines <- lineLengths
            return $ (length line) : moreLines
```

This will prompt the user to enter a line, and if it is an empty line then it will return an empty list, assuming you don't care about the length of the empty line required to stop the interaction. Otherwise it will recurse and prepend the length of the line onto the list of lineLengths that was calculated.

EDIT:

If you really want a list of pairs, I think the best way is probably to use another function like this.

```
toPairs :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
toPairs [] = []
toPairs [x] = [(x,0)]
toPairs (x:y:zs) = (x,y) : toPairs zs
```

Then to combine this with the reading function we can do this:

```
lineLengthPairs :: IO [(Int,Int)]
lineLengthPairs = do
    ls <- lineLengths
    return $ toPairs ls
```

Comment: Good answer given how little the question gives you to go on.

Comment: The empty string should return a line length of 0, no?

Comment: It depends. Since the program terminates on the empty string, the only place that a zero could appear in the output is in the final position, and since the empty string is the only thing that causes the program to terminate, *every* output would have a zero in the final position. So you might as well leave it out.

Comment: Thanks. It really works! Now I try to use it, to make same thing, what is in task. Why I want to get list of pairs? My teacher wants so. And in task, it really should return 0, if there are odd number of rows.